# Windows version of the time command?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a built in command in windows similar to the time command?

I am looking for a way to measure how long it takes certain taks to run, and would like to use something more accurate than a stopwatch.

Answer (score 5):

There is a program called timeit.exe included as part of the [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en), which is a free download (and works fine on Win7, FWIW).

There are lots of complicated options for dealing with timing databases and such, but the "-s" option skips all that and just reports the time at the end:

```
timeit -s command
```

If you need to stick strictly to the built-in commands, I think you'd have to create a batch file with the following and compute the time-difference yourself (which is *possible* to do in the batch file itself, but overly complicated):

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%
command
echo %DATE% %TIME%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get-Date cmdlet in Powershell, but if you're after millisecond precision then this cmdlet isn't gonna do any good, since it returns a date and current time down to seconds.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you use that to measure program start time? Still trying to learn PS atm...